# Does Office.js have the ability to subscript or superscript textboxes?

Tags: office-js

My add-on currently accepts user text input from a pop-up dialog. I have this text pasted into a textbox on the sheet. Is it possible to make part of this text subscript?

Comment: Hi Connor, I would like to understand more about the request, Do you mean you want to make the text subscript in the cell?

Comment: Whenever a textbox shape is created on the sheet, is Office.JS able to alter the format of the text and make a part of it subscript?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported so far Excel JS API. I would suggest that you could submit your request on [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563), and upvote your request. Thanks.